# Disable template->title in Codeigniter

Tags: php, templates, codeigniter

I am using the Template library for Codeigniter and if I leave `template->title` blank, it 'guesses' what the title will be and inserts it in  tags in the content. I don't need to specify a title, how do I stop it from doing this?

Comment: Locate the place in the code where it guesses that and remove that part.

Comment: @MotiveKyle: What library are you actually using? There are several template libraries for Codeigniter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. I thought it was automatically adding the  tags and the title, but it was in the default layout. I had been looking in the header partial instead. Always something simple..